# How do I get the current Item of a CollectionViewCell, Using a Button in the Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, database, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a question about finding the selected Item of my CollectionViewCells. I want to bring the Data to another ViewController and then edit and save it to the selected Item of my Cells? The Problem is that there my current Item is alway 0 and so my first CollectionCell? I use for testing a ItemList.txt file.

One of the cells:

[image: One of the Cells]

Here is my EditViewController:

```
class EditViewController: UIViewController {
    var itemList = ListItem.load() {
        didSet {
            ListItem.save(itemList)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var editTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var editView: UIView!

    //var currentItem = 0
    var currentText = ""
    var currentItem = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        editTextField.text = itemList[currentItem]

        editView.clipsToBounds = true
        editView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        editView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    }

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        editTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        editTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.editView.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

Here is my CollectionViewCell:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var btnTapAction : (()->())?

    @IBOutlet weak var listLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width * 0.1
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.47, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    }

    @IBAction func editButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Tapped!")

        btnTapAction?()
    }

}
```

Here my cellForItemAt in the Main ViewController:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            cell.listLabel.text = itemList[indexPath.row]

            cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
            cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.item
            cell.editButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            cell.btnTapAction = { () in
                print("Edit tapped in cell", indexPath.item)
                // start your edit process here...
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "edit") as! EditViewController
                viewController.currentItem = indexPath.item
                print("\(viewController.currentItem)")
            }

            return cell
  }
```

Here my ViewCollectionViewCell:

```html
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var btnTapAction : (()->())?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var listLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width * 0.1
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.47, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    }
    
    @IBAction func editButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Tapped!")
        
        btnTapAction?()
    }
    
}
```

Maybe there is an answer for that, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Are you saying that this line `print("Edit tapped in cell", indexPath.item)` always prints `0` for `indexPath.item`, regardless of which cell's button you tap?

Comment: And... do you also have a `func editButtonTapped(...)` in your Main ViewController? Because it looks like you are adding a `.touchUpInside` action to the button (in every cell) that calls `editButtonTapped(...)` in your Main VC instead of calling (or in addition to calling) `editButtonTapped(...)` in your cell class.

Comment: My editButtonTapoed I have in the CollectionViewCell and when I print the indexPath.item it prints the selected item, so this is working! But when I want to edit the text it is always the first item, it is the zero item!?

Comment: Your code shows `let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "edit") as! EditViewController`, and then you set `viewController.currentItem = indexPath.item` ... but where is the code that's actually *showing* that view controller?

Comment: The code is the first code snippet!

Comment: No, I mean how are you going from your collection view controller to your EditViewController? Are you calling `.present(...)` somewhere? or `.push(...)`?

Comment: Somehow it is working with this line: cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

Comment: Are you using a Navigation Controller? Have you set a Segue somewhere? The code you've posted doesn't show ***how*** you are moving from your Collection View to your EditViewController.

Comment: yes I do use a nav controller

Comment: OK... show the code where you use `self.navigationController.pushViewController(...)`

Comment: it is working with the cell.editbutton .... and in my ViewControllerCell I have a -  var btnTapAction : (()->())? and the I call it with the editButtonTap in the cell

Comment: Actually I got it now to work, that I can edit my cells, but I want to bring the text of the cell into the UITextField.text - but that's always gives back nil

Comment: When you tap the Edit button in the cell, do you see `EditViewController` slide in from the right? If so, did you add a Segue to do that?

Comment: I see the the viewcontroller slide from the bottom, I wanted it so and yes I added a segue in storyboard

Comment: OK - finally... See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not-quite-right.

In your `.btnTapAction` closure, you create a new instance of EditViewController. However, as soon as that closure exits, that instance no longer exists.

```
    cell.btnTapAction = { () in
        // you tapped the button
        // this line prints the indexPath.item to the console
        print("Edit tapped in cell", indexPath.item)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        // here, you create an instance of EditViewController
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "edit") as! EditViewController

        // here, you set .currentItem in the instance of EditViewController
        viewController.currentItem = indexPath.item

        // you print that value to the console
        print("\(viewController.currentItem)")

        // here, the closure exits, and
        // viewController no longer exists!
    }
```

At the same time you are running that code, your Segue is creating its ***own*** instance of EditViewController.

That's why `.currentItem` is always Zero.

Instead, you need to save the `indexPath.item` in a class-level variable, and then set `.currentItem` inside `prepare(for segue: ...)`:

```
class YourCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var selectedItem = 0

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let newEditVC = segue.destination as? EditViewController {
            newEditVC.currentItem = self.selectedItem
        }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.listLabel.text = itemList[indexPath.row]

        cell.editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.editButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


        cell.btnTapAction = { () in
            // you tapped the button
            // this line prints the indexPath.item to the console
            print("Edit tapped in cell", indexPath.item)

            // set your class-level variable
            // which will be used in prepare(for segue: ...)
            self.selectedItem = indexPath.item
        }

        return cell

    }

}
```

Or, another approach... Delete the Segue from Storyboard, and change your `.btnTapAction` to this:

```
    cell.btnTapAction = { () in
        // you tapped the button
        // this line prints the indexPath.item to the console
        print("Edit tapped in cell", indexPath.item)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        // here, you create an instance of EditViewController
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "edit") as! EditViewController

        // here, you set .currentItem in the instance of EditViewController
        viewController.currentItem = indexPath.item

        // you print that value to the console
        print("\(viewController.currentItem)")

        // present that instance of EditViewController
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```